# javascript: quotes problem: <input ... onclick='....value=\'2011-01-07 19:37\';'> doesn't work?

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick, quotes

Why does this not work, but is ok for "Y-m-d"?

```
<?php
echo "<input id=mindate value=$mindate>
<input type=button value=Today 
onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\'mindate\').value 
=\'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\';'>";
?>
```

On the page it looks like:

```
<input type=button value=Today 
onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\'mindate\').value
=\'2011-01-07 19:37:21\';'>
```

Must have something to do with all those quotes, but can't see where...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for mindate etc..
Try this:

```
  <?php echo "<input id=mindate value=$mindate> <input type=button value=Today   
      onclick='javascript:document.getElementById(\"mindate\").value  
     =\"".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\";'>"; 
  ?>
```

Comment: There is a subtle difference (in php). This is the first link I got in google. Check it: http://v1.jeroenmulder.com/weblog/2005/04/php_single_and_double_quotes.php

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotes for your HTML attributes.

```
<?php
echo '<input id="mindate" value="$mindate">
<input type="button" value="Today" 
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(\'mindate\').value 
=\'' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '\';">';
?>
```